# Getting a sum of events per different groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a structure like so:

```
country product     date_install    date_purchase   user_id
BR      yearly      2020-11-01      2020-11-01      10660236
CA      monthly     2020-11-01      2020-11-01      10649441
US      yearly      2020-11-01      trialed         10660272
IT      monthly     2020-11-01      2020-11-01      10657634
AE      monthly     2020-11-01      2020-11-01      10661442
IT      monthly     2020-11-01      trialed         10657634
AE      monthly     2020-11-01      trialed         10661442
```

I am trying to get the ratio of purchases / installs and the actual numbers of installs and purchase per `country, product, date`. `date_install` is a date of installation, `date_purchase` determines the day of the purchase and that the purchase has happened, `trialed` value in`date_purchase` means that no purchase was made for a user with `user_id`.

Desired output should look like this:

```
country product     date_install        installs    purchases       ratio
US      daily       2021-02-05          100         20              0.2
US      monthly     2021-02-05          100         50              0.5
US      yearly      2021-02-05          100         50              0.5             
US      trialed     2021-02-05          100         0               0    
# the next day
US      daily       2021-02-06          500         50              0.1
US      monthly     2021-02-06          500         100             0.2
US      yearly      2021-02-06          500         250             0.5             
US      trialed     2021-02-06          500         0               0    
# the rest of the countries & the rest of the days
```

The `installs` would be a number of the total `date_install` count for that day, country & product, `purchases` would be a number of total `date_purchase` events for each day, country& product.

The idea is that for a given country & day X people have installed an app, some of those have purchased a product and some not. Those who have purchased have a `date_purchase` value of a date, whereas those who did not have `trialed` value. But the total sum of those, who have installed an app is the count of `date_install` per country, product & date_install.

What I tried:

```
exp = df.groupby(['country','product','date_install']).count()
.sort_values('date_install',ascending=False).reset_index()

exp.groupby(['country','product','date_install'])['date_purchase'].sum().reset_index()
exp['total_installs'] = exp.groupby(['country','product','date_install'])['date_purchase'].sum().reset_index()
```

But I get an error:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

And I don't think that the way I am trying to achieve this is the correct one. What would be the best way / logic to achieve the desired result?

**Update**

After using @jezrael's answer:

```
df['date_purchase'] = df['date_purchase'].replace('trialed', np.nan)

exp = (df.groupby(['country','product','date_install']).agg(installs = ('date_purchase','size'), purchases = ('date_purchase','count')))
exp['ratio'] = exp['purchases'].div(exp['installs'])
exp = exp.reset_index()
```

```
exp[(exp['date_install']=='2020-11-18') & (exp['country']=='US')]
```

Returns

```
country     product         date_install        installs    purchases   ratio
US          catalog30US     2020-11-18          1           1           1.0
US          trialed         2020-11-18          4924        0           0.0
US          renders.100     2020-11-18          2           2           1.0
US          renders.20      2020-11-18          3           3           1.0
US          monthly         2020-11-18          37          37          1.0
US          yearly          2020-11-18          6           6           1.0
US          textures        2020-11-18          1           1           1.0
```

Which is not true, since the `installs` in each row should be the sum of total installs for a given set of `country & date_install`.

In the return I've updated the installs values for country & day needs to be the sum of all installs for country & day, in that case, each value for the installs needs to be `1+4924+2+3+37+6+1`, which would be the true installs for a given country & day, and then the ratios would make sense, now `installs == purchases`, which is not true. I am trying to answer: `for a given day and country, how many people installed & purchased different products and what is their ratio`.

I need it to be:

```
country     product         date_install        installs    purchases   ratio
US          catalog30US     2020-11-18          4974        1           1 / 4974
US          trialed         2020-11-18          4974        0           0.0
US          renders.100     2020-11-18          4974        2           2 / 4974
US          renders.20      2020-11-18          4974        3           3 / 4974
US          monthly         2020-11-18          4974        37          37 / 4974
US          yearly          2020-11-18          4974        6           6 / 4974
US          textures        2020-11-18          4974        1           1 / 4974
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need aggregate by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for count with missing values and [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) for counts with exclude missing values and then divide columns:

```
df['date_purchase'] = df['date_purchase'].replace('trialed', np.nan)

exp = (df.groupby(['country','product','date_install'])
         .agg(installs = ('date_purchase','size'), purchases = ('date_purchase','count')))

#sum per country and install date
exp['installs'] = exp.groupby(['country','date_install'])['installs'].transform('sum')
exp['ratio'] = exp['purchases'].div(exp['installs'])

exp = exp.reset_index()
print (exp)
```

Comment: I get an error `KeyError: 'purch for countases'`

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - oops, typo.

Comment: I've updated my question, do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: `Which is not true, since the installs in each row should be the sum of total installs for a given set of country & date_install.` Sorry, not understand.

Comment: In the `return` I've updated the `installs` values for `country & day` needs to be the sum of all `installs` for `country & day`, in that case, each value for the `installs` needs to be `1+4924+2+3+37+6+1`, which would be the true `installs` for a given `country & day`, and then the ratios would make sense, now `installs` == `purchases`, which is not true. I am trying to answer: `for a given day and country, how many people installed & purchased different products and what is their ratio.`

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - I hope I understand,  answrr was edited.

Comment: Perfect, just need to use `installs` instead of `purchases`, thank you very much!