# Counting values that aren't NaN in pandas group by

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66099869/getting-a-sum-of-events-per-different-groups-in-pandas/66100068#66100068)

I have a `df` like this:

```
country product     date_install    date_purchase     date_authentication           user_id
BR      yearly      2020-11-01      2020-11-01        2020-11-01                    10660236
CA      monthly     2020-11-01      trialed           trialed                            0649441
US      yearly      2020-11-01      trialed           2020-11-01                       10660272
IT      monthly     2020-11-01      2020-11-01        2020-11-01                    10657634
AE      monthly     2020-11-01      2020-11-01        2020-11-01                   10661442
IT      monthly     2020-11-01      trialed           trialed                       10657634
AE      monthly     2020-11-01      trialed           2020-11-05                    10661442
```

I am trying to get:

```
country product     date_install        installs    purchases     registrations  ratio
US      daily       2021-02-05          100         20            30             0.2
US      monthly     2021-02-05          100         50            40             0.5
US      yearly      2021-02-05          100         50            20             0.5             
US      trialed     2021-02-05          100         0             45              0    
# the next day
US      daily       2021-02-06          500         50            300            0.1
US      monthly     2021-02-06          500         100           267            0.2
US      yearly      2021-02-06          500         250           123            0.5             
US      trialed     2021-02-06          500         0             312            0    
# the rest of the countries & the rest of the days
```

I am trying to get the ratio of purchases / installs and the actual numbers of installs, registrations and purchase per country, product, date.`date_install` is a date of installation,`date_authentication` is a date of registration, `date_purchase` determines the day of the purchase and that the purchase has happened, `trialed` value in `date_purchase` means that no purchase was made for a user with user_id, and `trialed` in `date_authentication` means that the user has not registered.

The count of `installs` needs to be the sum of total installs for that day, same with `registrations`.

After using and trying to update [jezrael's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) answer:

```
df['date_purchase'] = df['date_purchase'].replace('trialed', np.nan)
df['date_authentication'] = df['date_authentication'].replace('trialed', np.nan)

print(df['date_install'].count())
print(df['date_authentication'].count())
print(df['date_purchase'].count())

# 2496159
# 112535
# 24311

exp = (df.groupby(['country','product','date_install']).agg(installs = ('date_purchase','size'), purchases = ('date_purchase','count'),registrations = ('date_authentication','count')))
exp['installs'] = exp.groupby(['country','date_install'])['installs'].transform('sum')
exp['registrations'] = exp.groupby(['country','date_install'])['registrations'].transform('sum')
exp['ratio'] = exp['purchases'].div(exp['installs'])
exp = exp.reset_index()
exp
```

But then `exp` has the same count for every metric whereas its clear that `installs>registrations>purchases`:

```
print(exp['installs'].count())
print(exp['purchases'].count())
print(exp['registrations'].count())

# 5035
# 5035
# 5035
```

Where is my mistake? I am trying to have the count of `date_x` events per `country, product, date_install` for `install`, `registration` and `purchase` noted by values in `date_install`, `date_authentication` and `date_purchase` where values are dates and not `nan / trialed`?

**UPDATE**

```
print(exp.isna().sum())
```

```
country                    0
product                    0
date_install               0
date_authentication        0
installs                   0
purchases                  0
registrations              0
ratio_from_install         0
ratio_from_registration    0
```

`sum` returns what is expected:

```
print(exp['installs'].sum())
print(exp['registrations'].sum())
print(exp['purchases'].sum())

# 143090
# 95860
# 13136
```

```
exp = (df.groupby(['country','product','date_install']).agg(installs = ('date_purchase','sum'), purchases = ('date_purchase','sum'),registrations = ('date_authentication','sum')))
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

How can I get the true numbers as in `sum`?

Comment: hmmm, I think it is correct output, because [`Series.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.count.html) exclude missing values, so it menas in second triple count are not (or same number) of missing values.

Comment: I think in `exp` are no missing values, so same number of count, check `print (exp.isna().sum())`

Comment: yes, exactly, there are no missing values.Btw, maybe need in second sum, not count - because in `exp` are counts.

Comment: ya, because you need counts, get number of all and all values exclude missing values, `installs = ('date_purchase','sum')` means create column `installs` and fill it by sum of column `date_purchase`. So you need sum `dates`? I think you need number of dates, not sum. But in `exp` are counts, so for total counts need sum

Comment: I do need the count of the `dates` in each column, but I can't get the right answer for some reason.